# symfony2 - error when trying to persist form data used in one-to-many/many-to-one

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a form for submitting an article. The form has a category multi-select box that pulls categories from the DB using my Category.php entity.  The form generates fine, but I get the following error when trying to submit:

```
Property "categories" is not public in class "Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Article". Maybe you should create the method "setCategories()"?
```

**Template Form Code:**

```
[...]
<div id="artFormG1">
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['title']) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['description']) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['source']) ?>
</div>

<div id="artFormG2">
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['categories']) ?>
</div>

<?php echo $view['form']->row($form['body']) ?>
<br />
<input class="button" type="submit" formnovalidate = "true" />

<?php echo $view['form']->rest($form) ?>
[...]
```

**ArticleType.php - Form Class**

```
[...]
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'artFormLeft')
    ));
    $builder->add('description', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'artFormLeft')
    ));
    $builder->add('source', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'artFormLeft')
    ));
    $builder->add('categories', 'entity',
        array('class' => 'NatknowEditorBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
        )
    );
    $builder->add('body', 'textarea', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce'),
    ));
[...]
```

**Article.php - article Table Entity**

```
[...]

/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory $categories
 */
public function addArticleCategory(\Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;
}

/**
 * Get categories
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}
[...]
```

**ArticleCatigory.php - article_category Table Entity**

```
[...]
/**
 *  @ORM\Id
 *  @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="categories", cascade={"all"})
*/
protected $article;

/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"all"})
*/
protected $category;

/**
 *  @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
*/
protected $isParent = 0;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set isParent
 *
 * @param smallint $isParent
 */
public function setIsParent($isParent)
{
    $this->isParent = $isParent;
}

/**
 * Get isParent
 *
 * @return smallint 
 */
public function getIsParent()
{
    return $this->isParent;
}

/**
 * Set article
 *
 * @param Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Article $article
 */
public function setArticle(\Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->article = $article;
}

/**
 * Get article
 *
 * @return Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Article 
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}

/**
 * Set category
 *
 * @param Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Category $category
 */
public function setCategory(\Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Category $category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}

/**
 * Get category
 *
 * @return Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\Category 
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}
[...]
```

**Category.php - category Table Entity**

```
[...]
/**
 * Add articles
 *
 * @param Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory $articles
 */
public function addArticleCategory(\Natknow\EditorBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory $articles)
{
    $this->articles[] = $articles;
}

/**
 * Get articles
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->articles;
}
[...]
```

**The Controller:**

```
[...]
$art = new Article();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager();
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('NatknowEditorBundle:Article');

        $success = "<h3>Use this form to add an article:</h3>";

        $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $art);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($art);
                $em->flush();

                $success = "You have successfully added the article '"
                . $art->getName() . "'!";

                $articles = $repo->findAllPastDay();
            }else {
                $success = "There was an error validating the form data!";
            }

            return $this->render('NatknowEditorBundle:Default:insertArticle.html.php',
                array('form' => $form->createView(), 'status' => $success, 'arts' => $articles,)
            );
        }
[...]
```

Heads-up:  I used the command line utility to generate the ArticleCategory.php entity, without error. However, I'm not 100% certain it's set up to do what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a setCatagories() to the Article entity to get past the posted error.

Could run into other issues. Getting many-many forms to work as desired can be tricky.

Become very familiar with:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: alright, I'll give it a try. I assumed the "addArticleCategory()" that was auto-generated would take place of the setCategories()...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still unsure as to why Symfony would auto-generate all the getters/setters fine, but skip the one-to-many. Seems weird...

Comment: Sort of a mismatch between S2 forms and the D2 generator.  The forms expect methods named get/set.  The D2 generator assumes you want to only add one category at a time hence an add as opposed to set.  Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You should name `addArticleCategory()` as `addCategory()`, then Symfony (master) will recognize it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about using:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

and:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

(Article.php)

Not sure if this was the problem, but I just ran into something similar.